# Given the variance of two legs in a population of right triangles, can you find the variance of the hypotenuses?

Tags: statistics

Let's call the population of the first leg of the right triangles X, the second leg Y, and the hypotenuses H. If I tell you Var(X)=v_x and the Var(Y)=v_y, can you tell me Var(H)? Of course, for all variables x,y,h of X,Y, and H respectively, we have that x^2+y^2=h^2

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For a function of two variables $f(x,y)$, from propagation of errors we have $$\sigma_f=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\sigma_x^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2\sigma_y^2}$$
where $\sigma=\sqrt{Var}$ means a standard deviation.

Here, we have $h=h(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2x=\frac{x}{h}$ and similarly $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{h}$. Using this in the above formula means $$V_h=\frac{x^2}{h^2}V_x+\frac{y^2}{h^2}V_y$$